# OpportunitySplit shows up as OpportunitySplitType in Query Plan?

Tags: soql, opportunity-split

Why is every query done over OpportunitySplit is always showing the OpportunitySplitType as main SObject Type in the query plan? Can this affect to the performance when trying to filter opportunities by splitOwners?

[image: Query Plan]